# Combine strings from array to an instance path

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

What I'm trying to do is combining a static instance name ('antwoordBox1', which contains a couple of movieclips with instance name)  with a dynamically selected object from an array (DefVragenArray[0][1][1]). But when I try to use the new instance path, I get the following error.

*ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property alpha not found on String and there is no default value.*

```
var newString:Object = 'antwoordBox1.' + DefVragenArray[0][1][1];|

// set the alpha of the selected instance to '100'
newString.alpha = 100;
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: What about `var newString:Object = '....' as Object;`?

Comment: When I add 'as Object; ' I get the following error : ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property alpha on String.

Comment: @putvande there's no alpha property on Object either.

Comment: Does the array contain strings which refer to instances within antwoordBox1?

Comment: Yes, the array conains the following, where the 2nd value is the instance name inside antwoordBox1 ; 

var vragen:Array = [
["foto.url",'antwoord_1', '1', 'fout'],
["foto2.url",'antwoord_2', '2', 'fout'],
["foto3.url",'antwoord_3', '3', 'fout'],
["foto4.url",'antwoord_1', '4', 'fout']
];

Comment: var displayObject:DisplayObject = antwoordBox1[DefVragenArray[0][1][1]] as DisplayObject;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, to get the name of your `MovieClip`, which is the 2nd element of your cell of your `vragen` Array, you should do : `vragen[i][1]` because your `Array` is :

```
var vragen:Array = [
    ['foto.url', 'antwoord_1', '1', 'fout'],    // 0 : [0, 1, 2, 3]
    ['foto2.url', 'antwoord_2', '2', 'fout'],
    ['foto3.url', 'antwoord_3', '3', 'fout'],
    ['foto4.url', 'antwoord_1', '4', 'fout']
];
```

So to access to your `antwoord_1` MovieClip inside `antwoordBox1`, you can do :

```
var newString:Object = antwoordBox1[vragen[0][1]];

    // the value of alpha is between 0 and 1, 0 is 0% and 1 is 100%
    newString.alpha = 1;
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks @akmozo, this worked for me!

antwoordBox1[vragen[0][1]]  was the selector I was looking for! Many thanks!